# IdentityModel2 TokenClient Resource Owner Password

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I am trying to get a Bearer token using `IdentityModel2` - https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2

Their github page says it support resource owner password

[image]

But I cannot see any way to add username/password and no example on how to do this.

How do I get token with username and password using `TokenClient`?

Answer (score 5):

Answer was simple, I just had missed the right method.  I will add here instead of deleting incase someone else stumbles across this:

```
var client = new TokenClient(
    _identityEndpoints.TokenEndpoint,
    "client", "secret", AuthenticationStyle.PostValues);

var response = await client.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(user, pass, "scope");
var token = response.AccessToken;
```